# Fitting an ARIMA with some coefficients forced to zero in R

Tags: r, time-series

Consider an ARIMA(2,0,2). If my ACF of standardized residuals suggests an MA(5), then my putative model will look like this:

```
P <- arima(x, order=c(2,0,2), include.mean=TRUE)
```

And my general model will look like this:

```
G <- arima(x,c(2,0,5), fixed=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA))
```

Here's how I figured this:

I have 2 AR's whose coefficients that are different from 0 and then 2 MA's whose coefficients are different from 0, so I have 4 NA's at the beginning.The general model has 2+5+1=8 parameters to estimate (2 for AR, 5 for MA, and 1 for a constant). Whatever position for AR or MA that doesn't have a coefficient that is different from zero, I fill it with a zero. So that is why the 5th,6th, and 7th positions are filled with zereos.

Is this true? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to specify that ma3=ma4=ma5=0. So the two models P and G are equal. I'm not sure why you are doing this.

Comment: Just after fitting my model, I have to assess its quality. So, I did residual analysis and now I am in the process of conducting over-parametrized analysis to see if adding an MA(5) to my model is worthy. Then, I will compare coefficients between models, see if the extra coefficients in the general model is significant or not, compare the AICs, and which model is more parsimonious to see if ARIMA(2,0,2) is a promising model or not. 
I have a question: What do you mean both models are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the general model is adding terms for MA(5), but you're forcing all those terms to be zero with `fixed = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA)`, so the two models are essentially the same.

```
> set.seed(1)
> x  = rnorm(100)
> arima(x, order = c(2,0,2))

Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(2, 0, 2))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2  intercept
      1.2546  -0.3933  -1.3614  0.3614     0.1172
s.e.  0.5075   0.4106   0.5237  0.5231     0.0123

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7115:  log likelihood = -126.24,  aic = 264.47
> arima(x, order = c(2,0,5), fixed = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA))

Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(2, 0, 5), fixed = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2  ma3  ma4  ma5  intercept
      1.2546  -0.3933  -1.3614  0.3614    0    0    0     0.1172
s.e.  0.5075   0.4106   0.5237  0.5231    0    0    0     0.0123

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7115:  log likelihood = -126.24,  aic = 264.47
```

If you want to actually compare an ARIMA(2,0,2) to ARIMA(2,0,5) then your general model should be:

```
> arima(x, c(2,0,5))

Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(2, 0, 5))

Coefficients:
          ar1     ar2     ma1      ma2      ma3      ma4     ma5  intercept
      -0.1300  0.6333  0.0183  -0.7853  -0.1296  -0.1167  0.0132     0.1174
s.e.   0.2908  0.1944  0.3009   0.2166   0.1413   0.1511  0.1675     0.0124

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7067:  log likelihood = -125.9,  aic = 269.79
```